# Swift 5: String prefix with a maximum UTF-8 length

Tags: swift, string, unicode, utf-8

I have a string that can contain arbitrary Unicode characters and I want to get a **prefix** of that string whose **UTF-8 encoded length is as close as possible to 32 bytes**, while still being valid UTF-8 and without changing the characters' meaning (i.e. not cutting off an extended grapheme cluster).

Consider this **CORRECT** example:

```
let string = "\u{1F3F4}\u{E0067}\u{E0062}\u{E0073}\u{E0063}\u{E0074}\u{E007F}\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1FA}"
print(string)                    // 
print(string.count)              // 2
print(string.utf8.count)         // 36

let prefix = string.utf8Prefix(32)  // <-- function I want to implement 
print(prefix)                    // 
print(prefix.count)              // 1
print(prefix.utf8.count)         // 28

print(string.hasPrefix(prefix))  // true
```

And this example of a **WRONG** implementation:

```
let string = "ar\u{1F3F4}\u{200D}\u{2620}\u{FE0F}\u{1F3F4}\u{200D}\u{2620}\u{FE0F}\u{1F3F4}\u{200D}\u{2620}\u{FE0F}"
print(string)                    // ar‍☠️‍☠️‍☠️
print(string.count)              // 5
print(string.utf8.count)         // 41

let prefix = string.wrongUTF8Prefix(32)  // <-- wrong implementation 
print(prefix)                    // ar‍☠️‍☠️
print(prefix.count)              // 5
print(prefix.utf8.count)         // 32

print(string.hasPrefix(prefix))  // false
```

What's an elegant way to do this? (besides trial&error)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what do you mean for prefix. You may use the alternate form prefixes (repeated or alternate) until you get the 32-byte size. You may look on unicode about such special cases (e.g. one with 2 byte length and one with 3 byte length)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi A prefix is a substring starting at the start index. There many of these "special cases" and they can have quite a bit more than 3 byte (like in my example  has 28 bytes)

Comment: @MJK: I means: there are various *modifiers* which are 2 to 4 byte length. Unicode recommend not to have more then 16 ore 32 (now I do not remember) codepoints, but a "unicode keyboards" could insert them giving a infinite length unicode sequence for a single character [an additional reason why unicode strings could always be normalized]. In any case, I recommend you to start with Unicode codepoints (and only later to think about UTF-8encoding).

Comment: Reading the answer, I still think I didn't get what you were asking. Maybe something related to https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/ and then doing a inverse of normalization, by adding combining codepoints which will be ignored?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I don't understand what there is not to understand. I want a prefix with the first *n* characters (i.e. Swift-`Characters` aka. ext. grapheme clusters) of a given string so that that prefix's UTF-8-encoding is at most 32 bytes long while *n* is as large as possible.

Comment: Sorry. I'm here because of Unicode, only now I looked Swift documentation, and they (IMHO incorrect use) of the word "prefix". So you want to segment the start of a text in nearly (but not more) then 32 bytes sequences. You already answered, but note that a cluster could be longer then 32 bytes.

Comment: I see. But that is absolutely the correct use of the word "prefix" in this context ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring#Prefix)). And if the input string starts with a cluster longer than 32 bytes the solution will — as expected — return an empty string, so that's not a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered that `String` and `String.UTF8View` share the same indices, so I managed to create a very simple (and efficient?) solution, I think:

```
extension String {
    func utf8Prefix(_ maxLength: Int) -> Substring {
        if self.utf8.count <= maxLength {
            return Substring(self)
        }

        var index = self.utf8.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: maxLength+1)
        self.formIndex(before: &index)
        return self.prefix(upTo: index)
    }
}
```

---

### Explanation (assuming `maxLength == 32` and `startIndex == 0`):

The first case (`utf8.count <= maxLength`) should be clear, that's where no work is needed.
For the second case we first get the utf8-index `33`, which is either

- A: the endIndex of the string (if it's exactly 33 bytes long),
- B: an index at the start of a character (after 33 bytes of previous characters)
- C: an index somewhere in the middle of a character (after <33 bytes of previous characters)

So if we now move our index back one character (with `formIndex(before:)`) this will jump to the first extended grapheme cluster boundary before `index` which in case A and B is one character before and in C the start of that character.
I any case, the utf8-index will now be guaranteed to be at most `32` and at an extended grapheme cluster boundary, so `prefix(upTo: index)` will safely create a prefix with length ≤32.

---

**…but it's not perfect.**
In theory this should also be always the optimal solution, i.e. the prefix's `count` is as close as possible to `maxLength` but sometimes when the string ends with an extended grapheme cluster consisting of more than one Unicode scalar, `formIndex(before: &index)` goes back one character too many than would be necessary, so the prefix ends up shorter. I'm not exactly sure why that's the case.

EDIT: A not as elegant but in exchange completely "correct" solution would be this (still only O(n)):

```
extension String {
    func utf8Prefix(_ maxLength: Int) -> Substring {
        if self.utf8.count <= maxLength {
            return Substring(self)
        }

        let endIndex = self.utf8.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: maxLength)
        var index = self.startIndex
        while index <= endIndex {
            self.formIndex(after: &index)
        }
        self.formIndex(before: &index)
        return self.prefix(upTo: index)
    }
}
```

Comment: First, this shows why you should attempt your own solution! ;-) Well done. Unfortunately as you point out your original solution *appears to be* fragile (consider the meaning of "predecessor" when a utf8 index is passed to `String`, its possibly ambiguous). Your second solution uses iteration much as one using `makeIterator` does, though as it does less copying it should have a slight edge in efficiency, and hence "elegance".

Comment: O(n) is good for small n: simpler. Else you should go with https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Random_Access to check where a previous cluster start, and then go forward to see if there are other clusters. So: complex and you need Unicode database.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I don't need to do that manually, `String.formIndex(…)` already does that for me.

Comment: The improved solution works for UTF-16 too!

Answer (score 2):

You've shown no attempt at a solution and SO doesn't normally write code for you. So instead here as some algorithm suggestions for you:

> What's an elegant way to do this? (besides trial&error)

By what definition of *elegant*? (like beauty it depends on the eye of the beholder...)

*Simple?*

Start with `String.makeIterator`, write a `while` loop, append `Character`s to your prefix as long as the byte count ≤ 32.

It's a very simple loop, worse case is 32 iterations and 32 appends.

*"Smart" Search Strategy?*

You could implement a strategy based on the *average* byte length of each `Character` in the `String` and using `String.Prefix(Int)`.

E.g. for your first example the character count is 2 and the byte count 36, giving an average of 18 bytes/character, 18 goes into 32 just once (we don't deal in fractional characters or bytes!) so start with `Prefix(1)`, which has a byte count of 28 and leaves 1 character and 8 bytes – so the remainder has an average byte length of 8 and you are seeking at most 4 more bytes, 8 goes into 4 zero times and you are done.

The above example shows the case of extending (or not) your prefix guess. If your prefix guess is too long you can just start your algorithm from scratch using the prefix character & byte counts rather than the original string's.

If you have trouble implementing your algorithm ask a new question showing the code you've written, describe the issue, and someone will undoubtedly help you with the next step.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, those are great suggestions! But I think I found a more "elegant" (which I guess I would define as maximizing simplicity *and* efficiency) solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I like the first solution you came up with. I've found it works more correctly (and simpler) if you take out the `formIndex`:

```
extension String {
    func utf8Prefix(_ maxLength: Int) -> Substring {
        if self.utf8.count <= maxLength {
            return Substring(self)
        }

        let index = self.utf8.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: maxLength)
        return self.prefix(upTo: index)
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, so even without formIndex(before:) this automatically "rounds down" to the next smallest extended grapheme cluster boundary? Great! That's way simpler, why didn't I try that…

Comment: This occasionally breaks grapheme clusters. Eg. `"‍‍‍‍".utf8Prefix(32) = "‍‍"`

Answer (score 1):

My solution looks like this:

```swift
extension String {
    func prefix(maxUTF8Length: Int) -> String {
        if self.utf8.count <= maxUTF8Length { return self }
        var utf8EndIndex = self.utf8.index(self.utf8.startIndex, offsetBy: maxUTF8Length)
        while utf8EndIndex > self.utf8.startIndex {
            if let stringIndex = utf8EndIndex.samePosition(in: self) {
                return String(self[..<stringIndex])
            } else {
                self.utf8.formIndex(before: &utf8EndIndex)
            }
        }
        return ""
    }
}
```

It takes the highest possible utf8 index, checks if it is a valid character index using the `Index.samePosition(in:)` method. If not, it reduces the utf8 index one by one until it finds a valid character index.

The advantage is that you could replace utf8 with utf16 and it would also work.